# how can i send data correctly in react-native using reducer?

Tags: react-native

Hi okay maybe this question is not very common maybe yes i don't know, so this is it , i have this sigIn Function :

[image]

and this is my loginHandle function :

[image]

so as you can see i send the values completly different as i recive it so, why this still working i don't get it, help me understand please.

Comment: How are you getting userName and password in loginHandle?

Comment: okay , i write the signIn function , but my partner wrote the loginHandle function content , so i am trying to understand if it works because i am not really sending the user and password and in that case maybe that means that it works because i recibe a token so, when i ask for the token it exist so ..

Comment: i am not sure :(

Comment: previously i had a temporal model , before the api implementation so that is why i receive  an object ...

Answer (score 0):

okay this is why i was not getting the user and password XD